# last row is being deleted instead of clicked row in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I want to delete a row from html table on button click using ReactJS. The problem is that on clicking delete button always last row is being deleted instead of the row that is clicked. Please tell what is the issue with my code?

**code:**

```
var RecordsComponent = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            rows: ['row1', 'row2', 'row3'],
            newValue: "new value"
        }
    },
    render : function() {
        return (
            <div>
                <table>
                    <tbody>
                    {this.state.rows.map((r) => (
                        <tr>
                            <td>{r}</td>
                            <td>
                                <button onClick={this.deleteRow}>Delete</button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    ))}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <input trype="text" id={"newVal"} onChange={this.updateNewValue}></input>
                <button id="addBtn" onClick={this.addRow}>ADD</button>
            </div>
        );
    },
    updateNewValue: function(component) {
        this.setState({
            newValue: component.target.value
        });
    },
    addRow : function() {
        var rows = this.state.rows
        rows.push(this.state.newValue)
        this.setState({rows: rows})
    },
    deleteRow : function(record) {
        var index = -1;
        var clength = this.state.rows.length
        for( var i = 0; i < clength; i++ ) {
            if( this.state.rows[i].value === record.target.value ) {
                index = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        var rows = this.state.rows
        rows.splice( index, 1 )
        this.setState( {rows: rows} );
    }
});

React.render(<RecordsComponent/>, document.getElementById('display'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You need pass a param on func deleteRow

```
<button onClick={() => this.deleteRow(r)}>Delete</button>
```

I refactor a litte bit of your func

```
deleteRow : function(record) {
    this.setState({
        rows: this.state.rows.filter(r => r !== record)
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In `deleteRow` you are looking for the index of the row that matches `record.target.value` (`record` is actually an event), but `event.target.value` is blank so the index remains `-1`, and `rows.splice(-1, 1)` deletes the last element.

You should pass the row data itself, like:

```
<button onClick={e => this.deleteRow(r)}>Delete</button>
```